# Using system.io.ports c# Windows IoT Univeral

Tags: c#, io, iot

I am working on a Windows IoT universal app and I need access to a serial port. Normally I would use:

```
using System.IO.Ports;
```

But that code is generating an error saying that the namespace does not exist and I can't find a reference to add to fix it.

Comment: is com1 found in your device manager?

Comment: Yor should add the reference to the .NET dll library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows IoT you have to use [`Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv4.5.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) namespace to access serial ports. You have to have [Windows 10 IoT Extension SDK](https://connect.microsoft.com/windowsembeddedIoT/Downloads/) (installer should be bundled with the Windows 10 image file for you board, you have to register there for downloads to be availble) installed and added as reference to be able to access that namespace.

Keep in mind though that if you use Raspberry Pi onboard UART will be inaccessible anyway, as it is used for kernel debugger.